# Autocomplete on multicolumn combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Good day

I have a standard WPF combo box that displays 2 fields with the following code:

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Surname" />
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I need to be able 'search' for a value in the combo box (the IsTextSearchable and TextSearch.TextPath make no difference [and as I understand have nothing to do with search/autocomplete functionality]). As is, when I type in the combo box nothing happends. I have managed to keep the drop down open but no luck with finding a match according what was typed. Any help, links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You could do a property of Surname + FirstName, and then on an event for example KeyUp, filter the itemssource, so your items would return only those items which contain the letters typed in within Surname + FirstName. Maybe there is a better way, but this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that TextSearch does not work with MultiBinding:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de5e6589-13f2-44a4-a92b-16359932baee/textsearchtext-on-combobox-using-itemtemplate?forum=wpf

You could build another property on the item that you bind to and then use that instead of the MultiBinding. That way, you can use the built-in TextSearch functionality instead of making your own.

Comment: I'm performing binding directly from a datatable. I edited the SQL statement to concatenate the first name and surname and tried to implement the functionality in that way but no luck. Am I completely misunderstanding you or is this kind of the same principal that you suggested I try?

Comment: I just did a test on a different database with the same table (table structure is identical) but it contains different data and the functionality worked! This second table does not contain any duplicate values in the surname or name field. Is this perhaps the problem? In the 'production' database the table contains surname values which are identical; e.g. Smith, John and Smith, Paul are entries.

Comment: Did you search for 'Smith'? From my understanding, the built-in text search only works for prefixes. So in this case searching for 'John' or 'Paul' would not return anything unless those are surnames.